Wiring two duplex switches
I have two duplex switches (4 controls) which I would like to replace with just two normal single switches.
Current setup:
1 switch for the ceiling light within the ceiling fan,
1 switch for the ceiling fan,
1 switch for a wall outlet,
1 switch for an outdoor flood light
Currently the fan switch needs to be always in the on position in order to use the fan and light within it.
Future setup:
1 switch for the ceiling light in the fan,
1 switch for the outdoor flood light,
Wire the fan directly to power(it has a remote to control speed and power),
Delete the switch for the wall outlet
I don’t have a need for a switch control outlet and my ceiling fan has a remote to control it and the fan power switch always needs to be powered in order for the light switch to work.
I got a little confused with all the wires coming in and how the current switches are setup. It looks like some of the power wires are taped together and there is a jumper wire going to the switch on the right.
The black fan wire and red ceiling fan light wire are in the same strand so it seems I have an extra strand of wires coming into the box that I don’t know what they do since there are 5 sets of wires coming into the box.



I think that can be done, and can even be done in that box. I am a bit hesitant to give specific instructions when I can't directly put my hands on the beast and confirm your analysis. And I doo not like the fact that whoever was in there last seems to have done a splice/pigtail with nothing but tape.

The outlet should be easy.  Just remove from the switch and pigtail properly to hot/power wire.  As @keshlam says, remove the tape and do it right.

If you number the wires with tags, draw a wiring diagram showing which wire is connected to which switch terminal, and tell us what happens where for each position of each switch, and the box dimensions, we should be able to help.  Do you know the approved methods of wire stripping, attachment to terminals, and  joining multiple wires with wire nuts?  (Kudos for the labelled photo and clear statement of what you have and what you are trying to accomplish.  BTW, there appear to be cables installed without clamps.  I would that too if I could.)

If all the information you provided is correct, and I have no reason to doubt it, your issue should be straightforward.
You've got five cables in the box:


2-Wire (Outdoor LT SL)
3-Wire (Ceiling Lt SL; Ceiling Fan SL)
3-Wire (Power; Outlet SL)
2-Wire (Power)
2-Wire (Power)

Keep your neutrals and grounds the way they are. They are wirenutted in their respective groups. Then, tie the red wire from "Wire 2" and the black wire from "Wire 3" into your power bundle. You will be left with two switch legs (Ceiling Lts; Outdoor Lights). Jump two pigtails from your power bundle, one for each switch. After that, it's a simple game of swapping the wires. Put a power wire and a switch leg on each single pole switch, and you're done. Please throw some electrical tape around those switches, it's not necessary, but I like to do it whenever I have a metal box.
As the other guy said, your post was very organized. The pictures were nice and labeled, making it easy to see what needed to be done. I hope this helped. Best of luck.
